# MySQL: multiple inputs search from database

Tags: mysql

I have simple MySQL code one table where is some row with some columns. Now I need when user use multiple inputs which defines parameters to search and show results with only used parameters. MySQL code not work correctly. Is there any option to do that?

**My table:**

```
   ╔═════╦════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
   ║ ID  ║  name  ║  location   ║ duration ║
   ╠═════╬════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
   ║   1 ║ Trip01 ║ High Tatras ║ 1 day    ║
   ║   2 ║ Trip02 ║ Bratislava  ║ 2 days   ║
   ║   3 ║ Trip03 ║ Kosice      ║ 3 days   ║
   ║   4 ║ Trip04 ║ Bratislava  ║ 1 day    ║
   ║   4 ║ Trip05 ║ Kosice      ║ 2 days   ║
   ╚═════╩════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM trips
where ('location' is null or 'location' = 'Kosice')
    and ('duration' is null or 'duration ='(empty)')
```

Comment: "doesn't work correctly" means what exactly? What result did you expect? What result did you get? `'duration ='(empty)'` is a) a syntax error because of the missing `'` after duration and b) doesn't make any sense because none of the duration fields contain the text `(empty)`.

Comment: And you said "when the user enters"...so presumably you have some kind of application which is accepting user input and then executing the SQL query? If so, then that application is responsible for constructing the correct query. If the user didn't enter a value in one field then you should not add anything in your `WHERE` clause relating to that field. Construct the query text gradually, based on which parameters are being used, and then execute the final result at the end. Don't just inject all values into a fixed query.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Backticks ` for column names . with apostrophes mysql thinks it is a string

```
SELECT * FROM trips
where (`location` is null or `location` = 'Kosice')
    and (`duration` is null or `duration` ='(empty)')
```